# Why when I modify UI in another thread (RxIoScheduler-4) it does work fine?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

```
presenter.login(user)
                 .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<?>>() {
                     @Override
                     public Observable<?> call(Boolean result) {
                         if(result){
                             Log.i(TAG, " login thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                             hideLoading();
                             presenter.saveLoginState(getIntent(),user,type);
                             finish();
                             return CampusFactory.getRetrofitService()
                                     .cache(new A(Integer.parseInt(user.sid),user.password));
                                     // TODO: 18-10-13 添加一个错误处理
                                     //.onErrorResumeNext();

                         }
                         return Observable.error(new Throwable());
                     }
                 }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .subscribe(msg->{
                     Log.i(TAG, " cache thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                     Logger.i(((Msg)msg).getMsg());
                 },Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

The first log in Flatmap is "I/LOGIN:  login thread RxIoScheduler-4", and the next log in subscribe is " I/LOGIN:  cache thread main",so the thread of Flatmap if RxIoScheduler-4, and I modify UI in this thread but it have no wrong and work well. That is very strange and the `hideLoading()` method is as following. Why can I operate UI in other thread?

```
public void hideLoading() {
    if (mLoadingDialog != null) {
        mLoadingDialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the case of `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` if you follow the code through you will find that work is posted onto a `Handler` (`mHost.getHandler()`) whose `Looper` is the main thread. I would assume that some other defensive checking, or similar mechanism is happening with your other UI interactions, however it is not safe to assume this for all UI interactions whilst not on the main `Thread`.

Comment: oh,yeah,you are right ! Thanks.I have seen that   dismiss() method,it is just what you said.